# How to Split equation in aligned environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, split

I have two sets of equation in aligned environment. The problem is that one of the equations (As shown in slide below) is too long to fit on a single line. I want to split this equation without changing the rest of my slide.

[image]

I want to move the last equation to right as indicated by the green marker.

here is the code:
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}

```
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{MWE:Split one equation in align environment}
%\begin{center}
\begin{align}
L_e(c_k^{(i)}) &=\log\frac{f_n(\tilde{c}_k|c_k^{(i)}=p)}{f_n(\tilde{c}_k|c_k^{(m)}=q)} \\&=\log\frac{f_n(\tilde{c}_k-p)}{f_n(\tilde{c}_k-q)} \notag\\
              % &=\frac{1}{2\sigma_q^2}\big( (\tilde{c}_k-q)^2-(\tilde{c}_k-p)^2\big) \notag\\
               &=\frac{1}{2\sigma_q^2}\big((p^2-q^2)-2\tilde{c}_k(p-q)\big)
\intertext{Combining $(m-1)$ terms yields}
\sum_{i=1}^{(m-1)}L_e(c_k^{(i)})&=\frac{1}{2\sigma_q^2}\Bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{(m-1)}\big((c_k^{(i)})^2-(c_k^{(m)})^2\big)\notag\\&-2\tilde{c}_k\sum_{i=1}^{(m-1)}\big(c_k^{(i)}-c_k^{(m)}\big)\Bigg)
\end{align}
%\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one of the typical ways to achieve this *alignment* with respect to the `=` sign:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{MWE:Split one equation in align environment}
  \begin{align}
    L_e(c_k^{(i)}) ={}& \log\frac{f_n(\tilde{c}_k|c_k^{(i)}=p)}{f_n(\tilde{c}_k|c_k^{(m)}=q)} \\
                   ={}& \log\frac{f_n(\tilde{c}_k-p)}{f_n(\tilde{c}_k-q)} \notag \\
                   ={}& \frac{1}{2\sigma_q^2}\bigl((p^2-q^2)-2\tilde{c}_k(p-q)\bigr)
  \intertext{Combining $(m-1)$ terms yields}
    \sum_{i=1}^{(m-1)}L_e(c_k^{(i)}) ={}& \frac{1}{2\sigma_q^2}\Biggl(\sum_{i=1}^{(m-1)}\bigl((c_k^{(i)})^2-(c_k^{(m)})^2\bigr) \notag \\
                                        &-2\tilde{c}_k\sum_{i=1}^{(m-1)}\bigl(c_k^{(i)}-c_k^{(m)}\bigr)\Biggr)
  \end{align}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Note how `&` designates the point of alignment. So we use `={}&` for the first part of the equation, and only `&` for the second part. Using `{}` ensures that `=` is considered a binary relation (since it contains an empty group to the right of it, in addition to some content to the left).

---

If you want the content to align with the `\Bigg` brackets, then you might be interested in this construction using `\phantom`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{MWE:Split one equation in align environment}
  \begin{align}
    L_e(c_k^{(i)}) ={}& \log\frac{f_n(\tilde{c}_k|c_k^{(i)}=p)}{f_n(\tilde{c}_k|c_k^{(m)}=q)} \\
                   ={}& \log\frac{f_n(\tilde{c}_k-p)}{f_n(\tilde{c}_k-q)} \notag \\
                   ={}& \frac{1}{2\sigma_q^2}\bigl((p^2-q^2)-2\tilde{c}_k(p-q)\bigr)
  \intertext{Combining $(m-1)$ terms yields}
    \sum_{i=1}^{(m-1)}L_e(c_k^{(i)}) ={}& \frac{1}{2\sigma_q^2}\Biggl(\sum_{i=1}^{(m-1)}\bigl((c_k^{(i)})^2-(c_k^{(m)})^2\bigr) \notag \\
                                        & \phantom{\frac{1}{2\sigma_q^2}\Biggl(}-2\tilde{c}_k\sum_{i=1}^{(m-1)}\bigl(c_k^{(i)}-c_k^{(m)}\bigr)\Biggr)
  \end{align}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

As a side-note: Consider indenting (and aligning) your code to make reading it a little easier to read and debug

Comment: Thank you for your code. But there is a problem. All the equality signs are not aligned in the output.

Comment: @NAASI: Sorry, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `multlined`  environment from `mathtools`. I took the liberty to replace the pairs of `\big( … \big)` and the like with `\bigl( … \bigr)`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
```

\begin{document}

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{MWE:Split one equation in align environment}
\begin{align}
L_e(c_k^{(i)}) &=\log\frac{f_n(\tilde{c}_k|c_k^{(i)}=p)}{f_n(\tilde{c}_k|c_k^{(m)}=q)} \\&=\log\frac{f_n(\tilde{c}_k-p)}{f_n(\tilde{c}_k-q)} \notag\\
              % &=\frac{1}{2\sigma_q^2}\big( (\tilde{c}_k-q)^2-(\tilde{c}_k-p)^2\big) \notag\\
               &=\frac{1}{2\sigma_q^2}\bigl((p^2-q^2)-2\tilde{c}_k(p-q)\bigr)
\intertext{Combining $(m-1)$ terms yields}
\sum_{i=1}^{(m-1)}L_e(c_k^{(i)})&=\!\begin{multlined}[t]\frac{1}{2\sigma_q^2}
\Biggl(\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}\bigl((c_k^{(i)})^2-(c_k^{(m)})^2\bigr) \\-2\tilde{c}_k \sum_{i=1}^{m-1}\bigl(c_k^{(i)}-c_k^{(m)}\bigr)\Biggr)
\end{multlined}
\end{align}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]